# PHP function parameters don't work properly?

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up a website using MVC, but I'm stuck at the very beginning.

In project0/application/controllers I have a pages.php file which looks like:

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

public function view($page = 'home')
{

if (!file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
{
    // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
    show_404();
}

$data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}
}
```

and in project0/application/views/pages two files named home.php and about.php, containing a "Hello world".

When I want to visit http://project0/index.php/pages/view/about, it gives me the 404 error: it seems the home.php or about.php files are not existing.

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, try a [`getcwd();`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) and then double check the results from that (your current working directory) against the relative path `'application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'`.  I would guess that you're not looking for your page in the directory you think you are.

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right I was working in the wrong directory. It works now!

Answer (score 1):

You just solved your own error. Your pages home.php and about.php are located in:
`project0/application/views`

But the code you posted is looking for them in

`project0/application/views/pages/`

Comment: Ok sorry, I meant that the two files are located in 'project0/application/views/pages'.

Answer (score 1):

I think whether your code will work depends on your setup (server setup and where your actual script runs from), but you can use one of several methods to make it more foolproof.

You can use the getcwd() function:

```
if (!file_exists(getcwd().'application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

Or you can define a permanent site path in your main config files, for instance:

```
$config['path'] = '/home/project0/';
```

...

```
if (!file_exists($config['path'].'application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

Comment: You're right, I was working in the 'wrong' directory. Thanks to getcwd() it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to specify the absolute path instead of relative `'application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'` - it may not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably checking for the file in the wrong place, I believe `file_exists` is looking for that path relative to `project0/application/controllers`.  Try this:

```
if (!file_exists('../views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

Comment: So you'll have to use the absolute path, as suggested on some other answers.